# RuntimeError: Start method 'spawn' was requested, but 'fork' was already set

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing, sanic

I'm trying to create a Sanic server for Nemo ASR. It seems Nemo uses some fork method, while Sanic requires spawn.

I've tried various ways to fix it but haven't been able to resolve the issue. I request experts to help me.

**Code:**

```
import nemo.collections.asr as nemo_asr

from sanic import Sanic

app = Sanic(__name__)  

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Error Message:**

`RuntimeError: Start method 'spawn' was requested, but 'fork' was already set.`

**Things I already tried, but nothing works:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
mp.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
```

```
torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
```

```
try:
         mp.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
         print("spawned")
except RuntimeError:
         pass
```

Comment: best solution is to not try to force them to use one thing or the other, instead launch each one as its own process, and have them communicate through a rest API.

Comment: I guess that would be more complicated, is there any other way like by threading? or can you share some document how to communicate 2 process?